# WPF Path detection for a section of the path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collision-detection, collision

As answered by Clemens ([WPF Paths Collision detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602400/wpf-paths-collision-detection)), it is possible to detect when paths touch / overlap with this code:

```
var intersectionDetail = path1.Data.FillContainsWithDetail(path2.Data);

if (intersectionDetail != IntersectionDetail.NotCalculated &&
    intersectionDetail != IntersectionDetail.Empty)
{
    // collision
}
```

Is it possible to do this with a section of a path? Or do I need to split the path into two separate paths and use them individually?

Comment: Depending on exactly what you are doing, this might not be the "best" approach. For our map editor app I needed to work out which points fall inside a shape the user draws. The solution I found worked best was to render the shape off screen and then iterate the pixels. You can render such that only where two shapes overlap do you get anything appears. Which could handle many shapes, complex shapes etc.

Comment: This might of course be totally useless to you. But you can work out the bounding box of two shapes to minimise where you're interested in or whether they might possibly overlap.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of trying different things, splitting the path seems like the best approach (and does work). I split the path down a known position and used the code like before - but updated to work with the two:

```
var intersectionDetail1 = path1.Data.FillContainsWithDetail(path2.Data);
var intersectionDetail2 = path1.Data.FillContainsWithDetail(path3.Data);

if (intersectionDetail1 != IntersectionDetail1.NotCalculated &&
    intersectionDetail1 != IntersectionDetail1.Empty)
{
    // collision with path part 1
}

if (intersectionDetail2 != IntersectionDetail2.NotCalculated &&
    intersectionDetail2 != IntersectionDetail2.Empty)
{
    // collision with path part 2
}
```

In this example, path 2 from the original has been split into path2 and path3. If path1 has a collision with either then they are detected separately.